# Есть ли разница в скорости выполнения циклов?

Tags: циклы, c++

Есть ли разница в скорости выполнения бесконечных циклов?

- for (;;)
- while(true)
- do while(true)
- for_each()

и как условия и итерация внутри них влияет на скорость их выполнения? происходит ли оптимизация при этом?

Comment: По первым трем нет разницы. А как вы собираетесь бесконечный цикл с for_each делать?

Comment: Много собираетесь сэкономить на циклах?

Comment: @dzhioev: в C# можно было бы.

Comment: Если хотите наилучшей производительности сделайте ассемблерную вставку :  

    JMP label
так на бесконечном цикле Вы добьетесь бесконечной экономии ресурсов системы.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Вы недостаточно лоулевельную технику предлагаете. Надо спец. процессор со встроенной командой бесконечного цикла!

Comment: @perfect: У вас проблема с производительностью, вы переписали алгоритм с квадратичного на логарифмический, применили собственный аллокатор памяти, всё равно слишком медленно, и вся надежда на бесконечный цикл?

Никто не знает точного ответа, потому что такой мизерный выигрыш (если он и есть) никому не интересен.

Не говоря уже о том, что разные оптимизаторы с разными ключами в зависимости от привходящих условий генерируют совершенно разный код.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать да вот пытаюсь для вопроса http://hashcode.ru/questions/232452/c-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE для значений размера unsigned long int код соорудить цикл длинный получается вот думаю можно ли сэкономить на циклах

Comment: @perfect Я думаю, что вы можете сделать бесконечный цикл чуть-чуть быстрее, заанроллив его.

Comment: Можно сделать еще быстрее, применив алгоритм с логарифмической сложностью, а не линейной. Например:  
http://e-maxx.ru/algo/bpsw  
Copy- Paste

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать объясни пожалуйста что такое "заанроллить"?

Comment: @perfect http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: Опять я со своими сумасшедшими рассуждениями, но вроде в for(;;) сначала выполняется for(/*это*/;;), а потом каждый раз for(;/*true == true?*/;) и for(;;/*это*/), а в while(true) только while(/*true == true?*/). Так может while(true) быстрее?

Comment: @perfect, у Вас там проблема с unsigned long для 32-разрядной машины?
(не делаете же Вы в самом деле решето для всех 64-bit чисел).

Просто используйте тип long long для индексов и все заработает.

Comment: @danpetruk, `gcc -S t.c` (g++ тоже) сделает файл `t.s` с текстом программы на ассемблере.

Чего гадать? Делаете примеры и смотрите.

Comment: @danpetruk: компилятор вовсе не обязан тупо следовать написанному. Если он может выкинуть бессмысленные операции (типа сравнения константы true с true), он обычно так и делает.

Comment: @VladD ладно, с компиляторами понятно. А что с языками, которые интерпритируются? У тех есть возможность ускориться?

Comment: конечно есть такая возможность. Но в основном она у тех языков, у которых есть прекомпиляция - например python.

Comment: @danpetruk: На самом деле, разница между компилятором и интерпретатором очень мала, если не сказать, что отсутствует. Интерпретатор, точно так же как и компилятор, может, по своему желанию, оптимизировать код, это ничем не запрещено. (Подумайте, чем вам процессор не интерпретатор — оптимизирующий! — исполнимого кода.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Есть чудесный сервис - [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/), где можно ввести кусок кода и посмотреть его ассемблерное представление ( при этом выбрать компилятор с++, синтаксис, и самое главное - соответствие между строками кода и ассемблерного листинга.

Итак, вводим три подопытные цикла (я привожу точный набор)

```
#include <cstdio>

void test1()
{ 
  while(true) {
    puts("hi1");
  }

}

void test2()
{
  for (;;) {
    puts("hi2");
  }
}

void test3()
{
  do {
    puts("hi3");
  } while (true);
}
```

(я использовал `puts` для вывода строки в консоль, так как это короткая функция с одним параметром, она не будет выброшена оптимизатором. `std::cout` превращается в целую простыню кода)

для gcc 4.8 (при параметрах компиляции `-O2 -march=native`) получаем

```
.LC0:
    .string "hi1"
test1():
    sub rsp, 8
.L2:
    mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    puts
    jmp .L2
.LC1:
    .string "hi2"
test2():
    sub rsp, 8
.L6:
    mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
    call    puts
    jmp .L6
.LC2:
    .string "hi3"
test3():
    sub rsp, 8
.L9:
    mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
    call    puts
    jmp .L9
```

Как видно, код абсолютно идентичный, только адреса разные. Другие компиляторы ведут себя аналогично. Только интелловский на минимальной оптимизации (`-O0`) нагенерировал кучу разного кода. А gcc даже при полностью выключенной оптимизации сделал такой же код, как и с включенной.

По факту, компилятор сделал практически идеальный код - сам цикл - это один `jmp`, тело цикла можно было бы попробовать сократить на одну команду, если вынести `mov` за пределы цикла, но нужно посмотреть детальнее на `puts`, может быть оно модифицирует регистр.

Конечно, нужно понимать, что не всегда код, который меньше размером, исполняется быстрее. Некоторые команды умеют "спариваться" и если одна команда исполняется за 10 тактов и другая также за 10, то разом они могут исполнятся 11 тактов (к примеру команды `mov` могут спариваться, если они используют разные регистры). Вот только компилятор знает эти тонкости, а человеку их запомнить очень сложно.